# network adapter stops working every 7 seconds

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a Dell Latitude e5430 with Windows 7 on it, and I can't get a wifi connection. My preferred network shows 5 bars, and there are 5 networks in range. It tries to connect, but every 7 seconds it loses track of all the available networks and has to start the connection process over again.

Comment: Did you [check this](http://superuser.com/questions/689634/i-need-to-make-windows-7-stop-disabling-the-wifi-adapter-when-the-wired-lan-is-c) ?

Comment: Have you ran hardware diagnostics? Does this happen with all WiFi networks or only one specifically? Has this ever worked properly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Wifi Drivers are causing the issue. In this case reinstalling the wifi drivers on your laptop may address the issue. You can download the wifi drivers for your laptop by providing your laptop details the following link:

http://dell.to/QjjZDA

Install the latest Wi-Fi driver and check if it resolves the issue.