# Ethernet connection makes the WiFi disable

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, internet

An Ethernet (LAN server) connection makes the WiFi disable automatically in Windows 8.1. By switching on the WiFi manually let only WiFi to run for few moments and the WiFi goes off again. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using a company PC then this is likely to be a group policy.  Many companies will set the PC to disable WiFi when connected to the corporate network by cable.

Comment: @ Chenmunka: It is already like this but WiFi is disabling every time by plugging the network cable. I can not be able to enable (with the network cable is connected) it more than couple of seconds and it goes disable again.

Comment: This behavior is built-in to Windows. The linked duplicate deals with 3rd party software and specific drivers and is not as broadly applicable.

Answer (score 4):

In Network and Sharing Center-> Change Adapter Settings-> Advanced -> Advanced Settings, move wifi to top most position

(Advanced option can be accessed by tapping alt key)

Connection preference is  in the order they are listed

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2526067

Comment: @ ichathan: It is already like this but WiFi is disabling every time by plugging the network cable. I can not be able to enable (with the network cable is connected) it more than couple of seconds and it goes disable again.

Comment: Are you using HP laptop?

Comment: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/Wifi-turns-off-after-ethernet-cable-plugged/td-p/3382887

Comment: Hp has a battery saver feature which disables wifi on connecting LAN. This settings is in BIOS. Check if yoir BIOS has a similar settings.

Comment: No it is Celsius H series. But power feature is also fine. It is a company laptop but under my control, so this is also not the case

Comment: See if this helps http://superuser.com/a/873046/143512

Answer (score 3):

- Press Windows+R, type "services.msc" and hit Enter
- Search for a service related to LAN/WLAN switch, I.E. HP notebooks will have "HP LAN/WLAN/WWAN Switching UWP Service", but it could different.
- Right click on the service, and select Properties
- Change the startup type to Manual (or Disable).
- Click Stop
- Click Apply

If you cant find any related service, make this changes to "WLAN AutoConfig" service. But this is strongly not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The answer about changing the connection priority appears to be wrong. That changes the priority of physical connections and wireless connections independently. That, as far as I understand, is only concerned with where to forward packets on which interface first. If there is an unknown address, broadcast, or multiple interfaces within the same subnet, this is where you tell windows which interface to send to first.

The wireless priority determines which wireless network to connect to over the other, if multiple networks that you previously connected to are available.

In Windows, historically you've always been able to keep an active LAN and wireless connection simultaneously. It's typical for System admins to turn off this feature via group policy settings as noted by chenmunka. This is purely done for security reasons.

If your PC belongs to your place of work, this is likely the case then.

==EDIT==

So it turns out I was misguided on the GPO setting. Looks like there does not exist the option of disabling wifi on a conditional basis of the LAN status being active or not.

All hits online suggest this is likely a bios feature. Any chance you can supply your exact model number?

Comment: Adding a comment in case you don't get notified via edits: So it turns out I was misguided on the GPO setting. Looks like there does not exist the option of disabling wifi on a conditional basis of the LAN status being active or not.

All hits online suggest this is likely a bios feature. Any chance you can supply your exact model number?

Answer (score 1):

Since this comes up on my search - on (patched) 8.1 and 10:
https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/give-ethernet-higher-priority-over-wifi-connection-in-windows-10/

Specifically, 
Béla Vajda  Antonin • 2 years ago
Hello!

I found the solution! In Windows 10 you cannot use the GUI just PowerShell.

The key is the interface metric number. The lowest number is the first in the order. My problem was: if I connected for VPN on wired Network then the adapter get the DNS from outside because may VPN adapter metric number was higher than Ethernet adapter...

Solution:

Run an elevated PowerSell (run as administrator)

Get-NetIPInterface

Then you will see your all interfaces with all information. Check the metric numbers and check the interface index.

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex (the number of selected interface) -InterfaceMetric (the number of metric)

This was my setting:

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 6 -InterfaceMetric 60

Set the wifi to the lowest index. (I can verify this works.) No GPO needed.

Comment: You can actually set the metrics from gui too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for me on https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Wireless-is-disabled-when-Ethernet-is-connected/td-p/4529436

"There is a service in the Windows called "Wired AutoConfig" that you need to disable to the Wi-Fi adapter do not be automatic disabled. Do it, and enable the Wi-Fi adapter, he wont be automatic desabled again."

In french I saw "Service de configuration automatique WLAN" and "Service de configuration automatique WWAN". I needed to stop the second one (Wwansvc) and it worked (on windows 10)!

**SOLUTION SUMMARY (tested on Win10) :**

- Try to disable the following windows service : Wwansvc
- Try to go in your BIOS and see if there is and option like "LAN/WLAN commutation"

Answer (score 1):

For my Laptop HP ZBook 15u G2, it was HP LAN/WLAN/WWAN Switching UWP Services that caused it. After disabling the service, it resolved the issue. LAN/WAN Switching in BIOS was not enabled.

Comment: Thank you!  This resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by disabling `LAN/WLAN Auto Switching` in the BIOS.

I have a "HP ZBook Fury 15 G8" with BIOS "HP T95 Ver. 01.09.02". The BIOS is entered with F10. Setting is located in `Advanced` tab, then `Build-In Device Options` link.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and annoyed me a lot for a long time.
My laptop is HP Pro Book 450, and running Windows 10 build 1903, this is my personal laptop, but I use it on my workplace network.

I solved the problem this way:

1. Go to search box in the Windows start bar and type command prompt, right click on the result and click  "run as administrator".
2. Type `netcfg -d` and press enter, this will reset all the network configurations on your machine (including the drivers for Ethernet and WiFi adapters).
3. Go to Control Panel ---> Device Manager ---> click on "Scan for hardware changes", this will refresh the settings and configuration of all your network adapter (Ethernet, and WiFi).

If this solution fails, then the problem is not on your Windows copy, it would be either  the BIOS (LAN/WAN switching), or  the company server.

EDIT (Important):
after applying this solution, which worked for me perfectly, I updated my Hp drivers, then the problem occurred again.
I searched and tried a lot of probable causes, and I finally (thank God) figure out the problem, DON'T USE ANY DRIVER FOR WIFI EXCEPT THE WINDOWS DRIVER.

I deleted from the system all and any drivers for WIFI, and the problem disappeared.

this is how to remove the other drivers:
1- go to device manager in Control Panel
2- go to network adapters ---> right click on the wireless adapter and select Properties.
3- go to Driver tab:
     a- if the Driver Provider is not Microsoft, click on Uninstall Device and check "Delete driver from computer", and continue
     b- if the driver is windows, click on "Update driver" ---> "Browse my computer for driver software" ---> "let me pick up from a list" ---> choose the driver that is not by (Microsoft), and click next, and then repeat step "a" above.

repeat step "b" until you deleted all the driver that is not by Microsoft.

the WIFI will turned on automatically after deleting the last driver