# Laptop's wifi goes out when my pc is connected to internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but my laptop's wifi gets disconnected from the internet when my PC is connected to the internet (wired). I tried to diagnose on the network adapter (on laptop), while my PC was connected to the internet and the diagnose returned, "The default gateway is not available".

edit: If i disable my network adapter on my desktop, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCP5.png)

then my laptop gains wifi access. It'll say my laptop has wifi access if its enable, just nothing will load

edit 2: repsonding to tyson in the comments,
So I ran the command on both devices and here's what I got
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GgMX.png),[Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkMSm.png), [Laptop - couldnt fit in in 1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgwZw.png)

Comment: That is standard behavior on most systems. Connecting to a wired network disables your wireless: https://superuser.com/questions/689634/i-need-to-make-windows-7-stop-disabling-the-wifi-adapter-when-the-wired-lan-is-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to make Windows 7 STOP disabling the wifi adapter when the wired LAN is connected](https://superuser.com/questions/689634/i-need-to-make-windows-7-stop-disabling-the-wifi-adapter-when-the-wired-lan-is-c)

Comment: I read the question differently than @music2myear.  OP are you talking about one computer or two? (I read it as 2... i.e. “laptop” and “desktop PC”)  (And to music2myear: my laptop doesn’t drop WiFi when Ethernet cabled, but it only “uses” the faster or wired connection.)

Comment: @Tyson I'm using two computers, ones a laptop and the other is a desktop when my desktop gets plugged into the internet, my laptop which uses wifi disconnects

Comment: Make the problem occur, open a ‘cmd’ window on both computers.  Type “ipconfig /all” on both.  There will be a lot of extra connections not in use probably but there will be one connection that’s more populated than the rest, that’s likely the one in use.... compare the IP addresses, are they the same that’s your problem.  Did you set static ip’s on these computers for some reason?  When the router/DHCP hands them out there’s usually not duplicates.

Comment: This must be something with the router configuration because the router drops the Wifi connections when you plug in the UTP cable.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to me.  The computers have different IP addresses.  Are there any other devices that connect to this router?  What router is it? Perhaps it has restrictions on number of clients?  I do agree with @bcs78 that something is odd with the router.  I don’t agree that the WiFi connection is dropping tho.. the screenshot shows your still connected to WiFi (and with a different IP than desktop).  The info in the screenshots all looks pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop and laptop are connecting a same router, when desktop is using wire network, laptop’s wireless network disconnected.

You need to make sure two devices use the different IP address from router, when your laptop connect to the  Internet, write down the IP address, set it as the static address. Then, insert network cable into the desktop, check the result.

Comment: hey, I just tried that, and I get the same results, I set it up correctly right? https://i.imgur.com/T6pV9hL.png (laptop)